# xcdatamodel is not entirely under source control in subversion xcode4

Tags: svn, core-data, xcode4

I have a project in xcode under svn source control.
It happens that the xcdatamodel is not entirely being put under version control by xcode.
Xcode show a question mark '?' status icon, while on the svn repository I can only see the empty xcdatamodel directory.

At first I would like to stay within xcode4 perimeter to understand why this could have happened, and how can I solve the situation with Xcode4 itself.

Then, if not possible, from the terminal window which svn command should I do on what files to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Terminal, you can get to the path of your `.xcdatamodeld` by drag and dropping the Core Data file into the Terminal window.

So "`cd`" into that folder.

Then type in `svn add .` (which adds everything in and underneath that directory... in other words, all the files of the Core Data model).

And then `svn commit`.  That will bring up the Subversion commit window and once you commit your data model, Xcode won't show a "?" mark anymore.

Comment: thanks, I did that and it worked fine. It is the first time I had this strange problem, do you know of any possible cause ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. There are a lot of variables in the mix here (xcode, svn client, your repository server, etc.) Could be a number of plumbing issues. If it keeps happening again with future projects, at least you know what to do to fix things.