# Can't keep .xcdatamodel under source control

Tags: svn, core-data, ios5

When I add a model version for my `.xcdatamodel` it will not add the model version to svn because it says the main folder is already under version control. How do I make it so all of my model versions are under svn without always deleting the `.svn` folder ever time I add a new model version?

Comment: I had a similar problem, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628787/xcdatamodel-is-not-entirely-under-source-control-in-subversion-xcode4

Comment: @Leonardo I tried that but it didn't work. It just said that the folder was already under version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by viewing the contents of the newly added model version and removing the `.svn` folder, then adding it to svn.